# DAX Power Pivot: "= CONCATENATEX(CALCULATETABLE(" how to avoid duplicates?

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I've seen similar posts before, but none of the solutions worked for me as my formula is complex and includes filters.

I'm trying to create a new column in a table, concatenating all matches from a column in a different table.(e.g. Order table concatenating all product names associated with a given order)

```
Full formula: =
CONCATENATEX (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        RoW_SIC_table,
        FILTER (
            RoW_SIC_table,
            RoW_SIC_table[Excel Company ID] = Row_main[Excel Company ID]
        ),
        FILTER ( RoW_SIC_table, NOT ( ISBLANK ( RoW_SIC_table[Broad] ) ) )
    ),
    RoW_SIC_table[Broad],
    ", "
)
```

I want CONCATENATEX to only concatenate unique values, and I haven't made it work with either DISTINCT or VALUES. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about like this?

```
Full formula: =
CONCATENATEX (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        DISTINCT ( RoW_SIC_table[Broad] ),
        FILTER (
            RoW_SIC_table,
            RoW_SIC_table[Excel Company ID] = Row_main[Excel Company ID]
        )
    ),
    RoW_SIC_table[Broad],
    ", "
)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Didn't expect this to work, I was so sure I needed the full table as a parameter in "CALCULATETABLE". Why not?

If I also wanted to sort everything so that e.g. I don't get "A, B, C" & "A, C, B" values?

Comment: Solved it! Adding parameters to CONCATENATEX()

Answer (score 0):

I used as reference this:

> e.g. Order table concatenating all product names associated with a
> given order

So what came to my mind is the following model:

SIC Table

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5vXK.png]

Main Table

[image]

"Data Model"

[image]

Result

[image]

```
ProductsListedByOrderIFBroadISNOTBLANK=    
VAR COrderID=SIC[OrderID]
VAR PIDWLineage=
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    CALCULATETABLE(SIC,
    ALL(SIC), SIC[OrderID]=COrderID, NOT(ISBLANK(SIC[Broad]))),
 "ProductID", SIC[ProductID], "ProductName", RELATED(Main[ProductName]))
RETURN
CONCATENATEX(PIDWLineage, [ProductName], ",")
```